# Check if text selection is in header/footer

Tags: ms-word, office-js

The Word Addin we created allows adding custom comments to text selections. Word does not allow adding comments in headers / footers. Because of that, users should get warned when text in a header/footer is selected.

- The selection's OOXML structure for text in body and text in header is identical.
- The Word UI itself disabled the review comments section when footer/header text is selected.
- When dumping the text selection object to te console, none of the object fields point to the selection being in header/footer.

How can be found out programmatically that text is selected in the header/footer?

Issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by looking at the `parentBody` property of the selection range. The `type` property on the `parentBody` will reveal whether the selection is in the 'Header' or elsewhere (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=office-js#type)).

**Example**

```
function determineSelectionInHeader() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        const HEADER_TYPE = "Header";

        // Retrieve and load 'type' of selection.
        var selection = context.document.getSelection();
        var parentBody = selection.parentBody;
        parentBody.load("type");

        context
            .sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (parentBody.type === HEADER_TYPE) {
                    console.log("This is the header");
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, `parentBody.type`  indeed did the trick. Was not aware that headers / footers have their own body.